# Power consumption on Android mock location and real GPS

Tags: android, gps, mocking

I want a small clarification. Is Android mock location mechanism burns power as same as real GPS?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself ?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is useless. Sharing knowledge and the experience is the key of the success as a community

Comment: But my point is, this trial should be quick & easy. Can finish in less than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: probably not. Here's why...

According to Android docs here (http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html):

> Location Services turns off its internal location providers and only
>   sends out the mock locations you provide it.

However, in my experience with a few apps that use mock location, the GPS "acquiring location" indicator still seems to be active and it still seems to use battery in a similar way. However, responses from the LocationProvider are immediate, so it's probably just an artifact and not an actual search.

I can't say that I've tested it thoroughly, though. Given that I don't have complaints on battery drain, I'd say the docs are accurate even if the indicator is misleading.